# Kotlin Firebase Realtime database transaction errors

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin-null-safety

I have the following code

```
   database.child("users").child(this.invitedBy).runTransaction(object : Transaction.Handler {
                override fun doTransaction(mutableData: MutableData): Transaction.Result {
                    val u = mutableData.getValue(User::class.java)
                        ?: return Transaction.success(mutableData)

                    if (u.numReferrals == null || u.referralEarning == null) {
                        // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                        u.numReferrals = 1
                        u.referralEarning = 1;
                    } else {
                        // Star the post and add self to stars
                        u.numReferrals = u.numReferrals!! + 1
                        u.referralEarning = u.referralEarning!! + 1;
                    }

                    // Set value and report transaction success
                    mutableData.value = u
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData)
                }

                override fun onComplete(
                    databaseError: DatabaseError?,
                    committed: Boolean,
                    currentData: DataSnapshot?
                ) {
                    // Transaction completed
                    Log.d("MUser", "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError!!)
                }
            })
```

When I run it, it gives me the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.test, PID: 5375
    kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.test.test.MUser$setReferral$1.onComplete(MUser.kt:229)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo$16$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:1006)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
W/System.err: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
W/System.err:     at com.test.test.MUser$setReferral$1.onComplete(MUser.kt:229)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo$16$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:1006)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

Here's my User.kt

```
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties

// [START rtdb_user_class]
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class User(
    var id: String = "",
    var name: String = "",
    var email: String = "",
    var userReads: Int? = 0,
    var userPlays: Int? = 0,
    var userWatches: Int? = 0,
    var paidDate : Int? = 0,
    var endPaidDate : Int? = 0,
    var paidStatus : String? = "",
    var paymentMethod : String? = "",
    var planid : String? = "",
    var firebaseUid : String? = "",
    var referralEarning : Int? = 0,
    var numReferrals : Int? = 0
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you debug and see exactly where it is crashing?

Comment: At which line of code does the error occur? What's the exact value of `invitedBy`? Please also add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: this is the line that's crashig

 if (u.numReferrals == null || u.referralEarning == null) {
                        // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                        u.numReferrals = 1
                        u.referralEarning = 1;
                    } else {
                        // Star the post and add self to stars
                        u.numReferrals = u.numReferrals!! + 1
                        u.referralEarning = u.referralEarning!! + 1;
                    }

Comment: might it be that u is null?

Comment: @MirianaItani `u` can't be null because it would go into the return statement : `val u = mutableData.getValue(User::class.java)
                        ?: return Transaction.success(mutableData)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at `onComplete` method:

```
override fun onComplete(
                    databaseError: DatabaseError?,
                    committed: Boolean,
                    currentData: DataSnapshot?
                ) {
                    // Transaction completed
                    Log.d("MUser", "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError!!)
                }
```

You are using `!!` operator when referencing `databaseError` parameter, but it can be null, so you can't use `!!`. To avoid that Exception just remove `!!` operator:

```
Log.d("MUser", "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError)
```

`databaseError: DatabaseError?` - it is a **nullable** object (nullable objects marked with `?` operator), you can't use `!!` operator on it if you are not 100% sure that it is not null.

Also you can use `?` operator on **nullable** objects to call its methods or properties, e.g.:

```
Log.d("MUser", "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError?.getMessage())
```

[More info about Null Safety in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).